# How to fix an UnsatisfiedLinkError (dlopen failed for prebuilt so file) in a JNI project

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, java-native-interface

I'm facing a problem with a .so file. It is similar to the problem mentioned [dlopen failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76486139/15289173).

I get the  error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library 
".../app/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libtrack.so" 
not found: needed by 
/data/app/~~YzzcbvvZ_4br3tcGPsvhrg==/com.example.myapplication- 
vgn78uUEwKAUSrgCzYSOVQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libcheck-libs.so 
in namespace classloader-namespace
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks.

This is file CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
project("check-libs")
add_library(lib_track SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
        lib_track
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libtrack.so
)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
add_library(
        check-libs SHARED
        check_jni.cpp)
target_include_directories(check-libs PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
find_library(
        log-lib
        log)
target_link_libraries( 
        check-libs
        android
        lib_track
        ${log-lib})
```

And build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    ndkVersion '25.1.8937393'
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11", "-fexceptions", "-frtti"
                cFlags "-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS"
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.22.1'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']

        }
    }
}
```